# Android activity has leaked window DecorView

Tags: android, dialog

I have an async task and in onPreExecute I have this error: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity has leaked window DecorView@db70191

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Zoznam activity = activityReference.get();
    if (activity == null || activity.isFinishing() || activity.isDestroyed()) return;
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    dialog.setMessage(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.Loading));
    dialog.setTitle(activity.getResources().getString(R.string.connecting));
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
}
```

This happens only in this situation: when the connection is slow and it is connecting to a server long time and the dialog message appears and the user suddenly manually **forceclose the app** (middle button on device, etc).

So logically the dialog window is not closed as the user forces the app to end. How can I avoid this? Usually there is no problem, only if the user closes the app while the dialog is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found an answer which helps me:

```
    @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dialog != null) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
    }
}
```